# Inside layout folder create multiple folder Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

**same xml file diffrent-diffrent folder**

like activity-main.xml

```
 layout  ->
            first-page ->
                         activity_main.xml
                         activity_main2.xml
           seccond-page ->
                         activity_main.xml
                         activity_main2.xml
           third-page ->
                         activity_main.xml
                         activity_main2.xml
           fourth-page ->
                         activity_main.xml
                         activity_main2.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new folder inside the res directory. The new folder you create can be your res source.

Open app build.gradle file and add the following code:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs =
                [
                        'src/main/res/layouts/activities',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/fragements',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/includes',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/items',
                        'src/main/res/layouts',
                        'src/main/res'
                ]
    }
}
```

[Repo link](https://github.com/harunkor/LayoutFilesInSubfolders).

[image]